# Can't send the string output (from a Python tool) to work as a input for a tool in a model (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcpy, python, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I have a model that uses the Feature Class to Feature Class tool. It needs 3 inputs (Input layer, location and output name). My goal is that a user would choose a layer, the model would create a new name based on the layer, and then it would export the layer to somewhere else. For testing purposes, the input layer is static, because I have no issues with that part.  Here is my model so far:

[image]

The change name is a custom tool that take a layer name, and return a string.  Again, for testing purposes, I deleted almost all the code, and left only the important part:

```
import datetime   
import arcpy   
import os  
name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
text = "lol"  
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, text)
```

Of course, on the tool properties, I made sure that the data type is a string for the output. I also tried Any type, and also tried changing the type to from Derived to Optional and Required.

But I always get the same error. Output Feature Class is not valid on the Feature to Feature tool:
[image]

and

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is some sort of bug in ArcGIS Pro. The work around is this:

1. Make the script output "Desired Name" a precondition to the FeatureClass to FeatureClass tool. Do not connect it to the parameter.
2. Open the FeatureClass to FeatureClass tool and type into the Output Feature Class Parameter %Desired Name%.

That worked for me.